# apache mod_rewrite, simple question

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I have domain and I am wanting to forward virtual folder to identify company e.g

```
www.domain.com/CompanyA
www.domain.com/CompanyB
```

CompanyA and CompanyB folders don't exist, and I want that to become the querystring e.g

```
www.domain.com/?CompanyA etc..
```

How do I do this with mod_rewrite?

Many thanks,

Answer (score 3):

Add the following RewriteRule:

```
RewriteRule ^/([A-Za-z]+)$ /?$1
```

This will capture any sequence of one or more lower and uppercase letters into the first match group (that can be accessed by $1). You may then use $1 in the second parameter of the rewrite rule to mean the string matched. For example, you could use:

```
RewriteRule ^/([A-Za-z]+)$ /render.php?page=$1
```

if you want to use a file other than your index.php (or equivalent) to handle the conditional rendering logic.

Comment: Thanks I got some progress but now I get You don't have permission to access /CompanyA on this server.

Comment: Does changing the rule to ^([A-Za-z]+)$ /?$1 changes anything?

Comment: It loads but doesn't pick up query string

Comment: Are you using RewriteBase set to "/"?

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?query=$1 [L,QSA]
```

QSA let you keep incoming query string intact.

Comment: Thanks but I need to keep the index.php can't rename in my framework :(